# Orientation issue when app enters into background

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, some UI issue happening because of method `viewWillTransitionToSize` called each time in following conditions.

- When app enters background.
- When you press power button.
- When you change device orientation in active state.
- Also when resizing the app in multitasking mode.

I have issue with my top two conditions, it should not get called for those two conditions. As per my requirement, it should get called only when orientation changes and when application is in multitasking mode.
If i use `transitionDuration()`, my problem has solved but as per my code reviewer it is kind of hacks not a proper way to handle.
Any alternative for it?